# How to write the general solution for the recurrence relation: $x_{n+1} = x_n e ^ {\frac{1}{x_n}}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$, with $x_0>0$ and satisfying the recurrence relation: $$x_{n+1} = x_n   e ^ {\frac{1}{x_n}},$$ how you go about writing $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$, and the difference $x_{n+1} - x_n$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt one can find a closed formula giving $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$, however
for every $x\in {\mathbb R}$, one has
\begin{equation}
e^x \ge 1 + x
\end{equation}
It follows that if $x_n > 0$,
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}\ge x_{n}(1 + \frac{1}{x_{n}}) = x_{n}  + 1
\end{equation}
hence $x_n \ge x_0 + n$ when $x_0 > 0$, and $x_n\to \infty$.

When $x_0 < 0$, we see that $x_n< 0$ for all $n$, and $x_n$ increases. It is easy to conclude that $x_n\to 0$.